# BLE GATT there's no notification data after writing

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have one custom service (`0000fff0`), and in the service there are notifiable characteristic(`0000fff1`) and writable characteristic(`0000fff2`). (there is no 'read' characteristic)
According to the API documentation of my bluetooth device, 
data packet format is as follows:

```
68 xx xxxx xx ... xx 16
(one pair of 'xx' is a byte hex code)
```

- 68 -> header (1byte)
- xx -> function code (1byte)
- xxxx -> data length    (2byte)
- ... ->    data (...byte)
- xx ->    checksum (1byte)
- 16 -> tail    (1byte)

and example data request code, that is written on the doc, is

```
68 06 01 00 00 6f 16
```

- 68 -> header
- 06 -> function code
- 01 00 -> data length
- 00 -> data
- 6f -> checksum
- 16 -> tail

then based on the doc, i should get response from device like `68 86 0e 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 43 16`, but i got nothing from the notification characteristic.

From onCharacteristicWrite callback i got also `GATT_SUCCESS`. so i reckon writing is not the problem. and the notification works as well for the other heartrate devices(standard `HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT` characteristic).

The document says nothing about that the response data will come through notification characteristic. I just assume it might be there.

I'm wondering whether the example on the API document is wrong or I miss something? Is there some sort of "request-response" format like http communication? so every time i write something on writable characteristic, i got some response from the device or something like that,...

```
    private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
        new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        int childPosition, long id) {
                if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                            mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                    final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                        // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                        // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                        if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                        }
                        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                    }
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                characteristic, true);
                    }

                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
                        if(SampleGattAttributes.BLACK_WRITE.equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())){
                            mBluetoothLeService.writeRemoteCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }
                    }

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
};
public void writeRemoteCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    if (SampleGattAttributes.BLACK_WRITE.equals(characteristic.getUuid().toString())) {
        byte[] data = new byte[7];
        data[0] = (byte)0x68;
        data[1] = (byte)0x06;
        data[2] = (byte)0x01;
        data[3] = (byte)0x00;
        data[4] = (byte)0x01;
        data[5] = (byte)0x70;
        data[6] = (byte)0x16;

        characteristic.setValue(data);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE,characteristic);
        }
    }
```

...

Comment: Did you subscribe to that characteristic?

Comment: yes i did... I added snip of my source code.